# Loopback 3 Queries not returning expected results for MySQL data field

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a content model that looks like:

```
{
  "name": "content",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "Object",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
```

Example of this data in MySQL looks like this:
[image]

I've tried querying this data both with REST and the Node API and haven't been able to query by any of the nested object fields inside of the "data" database field. A few examples that don't work:

```
      contentModel.findOne({ where: { "data.url": url } }, function (
        err,
        content
      ) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("find:", content);
      });
```

```
const filter = encodeURI(`{"where":{"systemid":"${contentType}"}}`);
      let url = `${apiUrl}contentTypes?filter=${filter}`;
      let contentTypeRecord = await this.getAxios().get(url);
```

I've also tried many queries in the loopback swagger ui. I usually get no results or it returns all the content records.

The above data access attempts do however work if I have the same data setup in MongoDb.

What am I doing wrong? Loopback should presumably be parsing the object in the data field and allowing me to filter on it.

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, LoopBack does not support query filters on nested properties. According to [this comment](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517#issuecomment-469072881), there is a limited support in PostgreSQL and MongoDB connectors:

> @michelgokan as you'll see from the thread:
>
> - There is [some support in postgres connector](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517#issuecomment-362767424)
> - Mongo also has some basic support (only for dot nested properties)
> - Further support isn't going to be added to other RDB connectors as loopback 3 is in LTS and no longer accepting new feature PRs
> - Loopback 3 ends LTS at the end of 2019 so it's even less likely to be added.
>
> Options are:
>
> - Write the custom SQL yourself as a custom endpoint
> - Create an alternate connector for something like [Knex](https://knexjs.org/) or [Bookshelf](https://bookshelfjs.org/) that has support (big job)
> - Do the filtering in memory
> - Use json for the nested data to use dot queries in something like mongo or postgres
> - Look at migrating to loopback next which may add support in the future

It seems that MySQL supports querying of JSON data, see [docs for `JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), thus it should be possible to implement this feature in `loopback-connector-mysql`. Feel free to open an issue in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues. A pull request would be even better! ❤️

Comment: thanks @Miroslav Bajtoš,  but I'm not sure that is the exact same use case - The Mongo connector for my original question works perfectly. I'd be really surprised if this couldn't work with RDMS -seems like such as common use case (storing a JSON object in a db field and wanting to filter in it). If I can't get this work, I'm really going to have to rethink using Loopback at all for my project, ugh.

Comment: Yes, I agree it could work. Now we need somebody to implement and contribute the necessary changes ‍♂️